# Calculate fraction as value relative to other fractions

Tags: javascript, math

Apologies that I can't show code I'm just not sure how to go about this.

I would like to achieve something like `display: flex/grid` does with fractions:

Given a container width: `200px`

And items: `[0.5, 1, 50px]`

I should be able to calculate the fractional ones relative to each other:

```
item1: 50 (half the size of item 2)
item2: 100 (double the size of item 1)
item3: 50 (static size not a fraction)
```

```js
const totalSize = 900;

const items = [1, 0.2, 75, 0.6, 1, 100];

const totalStaticSize = items.filter(n => n > 1).reduce((acc, n) => acc + n, 0);

const derivedItems = items.map(item => {
  if (item > 1) {
    // A static value.
    return item;
  }
  
  // How to calculate this fractional item relative to others?
  return item;
});

console.log(derivedItems);
```

Comment: Those items are not valid javascript.  Are the values encoded as strings?

Comment: Just an example, I know which are non-fractional but for this lets assume anything over 1 is. Added a runnable snippet.

Comment: `item1 = (item1 / (item1 + item2)) * space available`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After subtracting the static items, calculate the sum of fractional items, then you can calculate the percentage of each value relative to the remaining container width (minus the static item sum):

```
const totalSize = 900;
const items = [1, 0.2, 75, 0.6, 1, 100];
const totalStaticSize = items.filter(n => n > 1).reduce((acc, n) => acc + n, 0);
const sum = derivedItems.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
const percentages = derivedItems.map(d => d / sum);
const relativeToContainer = percentages.map(p => p * (totalSize - totalStaticSize));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let compute = (values, total) => {
  let parts = values.map(value => ({value: parseFloat(value), absolute: value.endsWith('px')}));
  let totalAbsolutes = parts.filter(p => p.absolute).reduce((sum, p) => sum + p.value, 0);
  let totalFractions = parts.filter(p => !p.absolute).reduce((sum, p) => sum + p.value, 0);
  return parts.map(p => (p.absolute ? p.value : p.value / totalFractions * (total - totalAbsolutes)) + 'px');
};

let computedValues = compute(['0.5', '1', '50px'], 200);
console.log(computedValues);
```

Comment: Inputs are not the same as what OP posted.