# react-virtualized supports Relative Lengths

Tags: react-virtualized

[React-virtualized](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized) is really a nice library. Just wondering whether it supports relative lengths in *height*/*width* property. Most of its examples are using just number pixels.

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Table
    width={300}
    height={300}
    headerHeight={20}
    rowHeight={30}
    rowCount={list.length}
    rowGetter={({index}) => list[index]}>
    <Column label="Name" dataKey="name" width={100} />
    <Column width={200} label="Description" dataKey="description" />
  </Table>,
  document.getElementById('example'),
```

[Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units) to CSS units *Relative length units*

Comment: No it doesn't, you'll have to convert relative units yourself into pixels

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! It seems the Table in material-ui is also use pixel for column width. Any idea to do response layout for the columns?

Comment: You will need to observe the size of the component (author made a component called AutoSizer for this, or you can alternatively use ResizeObserver or a polyfill yourself). Also the author made a more lightweight version of virtualized called react-window FYI. Then you would need to take the width of the component and divy it up to the columns which you want to be relative https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58737641/calculate-fraction-as-value-relative-to-other-fractions